# Convert non-nullable to nullable in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I have an Entity class as below:

```
@Entity(name = "Person")
@Table(name = "person")
class Person(
    _firstName: String? = null,
    _lastName: String?,
    _address: String? = null)
) {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "native")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "native", strategy = "native")
    var personId: Long? = null

    var firstName = _firstName
    var lastName = _lastName
    var address = _address
    
}
```

The repository is as :

```
@Repository
interface PersonRepository : JpaRepository<Person?, Long?> {
fun findByIdAndFirstName (personId: Long, firstName: String): Person?
}
```

In my service class I am doing a `findById(personId)` and getting an `Optional<Person?>` in return.

While writing the testcases I am running into an issue with the `Optional`.

```
@Test
    fun `test my changes`() {
        every { personRepository.findById(PERSON_ID) } answers { Optional.of(getPerson())}

    }
```

```
private fun getPerson(): Person {
        return Person(_firstName = "First Name", _lastName = "Last Name", _address = "Address")
    }
```

Since my `getPerson()` directly return the Person entity via a constructor the response is of type Person which is `non-nullable`.
But `personRepository.findById(PERSON_ID)` expects a nullable type `Optional<Person?>`.

Getting this as compilation error in my test class:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Optional<Person?>!
Found:
Optional<Person>
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Have yo you try `getPerson(): Person?`

Comment: Yes I did. It does not seem to work :(

Comment: Why `PersonRepository : JpaRepository<Person?, Long?>` in the first place? That is what causes the `Optional<Person?>`, which is a type that really doesn't make much sense... Why not `PersonRepository : JpaRepository<Person, Long>`?

Comment: Ah apologies. I have another method in the `PersonRepository` called `fun findByIdAndFirstName (): Person?`. I omitted that in the main question. So I would need it that way. Updated the quesiton.

Comment: Can you try using `returns` instead?

Comment: with `returns` it gives the same error:
`Required:
Optional<Person?>!
Found:
Optional<Person>
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast it to nullable:

```
@Test
fun `test my changes`() {
    every { personRepository.findById(PERSON_ID) } answers {
        Optional.of(getPerson()) as Optional<Person?>
    }
}
```

However (as Sweeper said in the comment) the type `Optional<Person?>` doesn't make much sense, and it looks like your JpaRepository should be parameterized on non-nullables. If it was, then `findById` would return `Optional<Person>` and you wouldn't have this issue.